# How do I paste the Windows clipboard into my PuTTY session, using only the keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, putty, clipboard

I would like to paste text the Windows clipboard into my PuTTY session using only the keyboard. I am running PuTTY 0.60 on Windows XP.

Usage example: I just selected a bunch of **nice** text inside of my Emacs on Windows. I then shift my focus to a Putty window. Then I press the magic keyboard shortcut, and the application waiting for input on the other side **gets some**.

I have tried the [keyboard shortcut to paste into `cmd`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>](https://superuser.com/questions/16313/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-in-windows-command-prompt), but it doesn't paste the clipboard into my PuTTY window.

This [question and answer about opening the system menu using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>](https://superuser.com/questions/149765/how-to-open-the-upper-left-context-menu-via-keystroke-for-putty-on-windows) looks interesting, but it doesn't bring me closer to an answer.

So, does anyone know how can I paste the Windows clipboard into my PuTTY session using only the keyboard?

Comment: This is also useful with terminal programs which use mouse events for themselves, such as `mcedit`. It's impossible to paste into these with a right mouse click.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> to paste text.

From PuTTY [documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html):

> Pasting is done using the right button (or the middle mouse button, if you have a three-button mouse and have set it up; see section 4.11.2). (Pressing Shift-Ins, or selecting ‘Paste’ from the Ctrl+right-click context menu, have the same effect.) When you click the right mouse button, PuTTY will read whatever is in the Windows clipboard and paste it into your session, exactly as if it had been typed at the keyboard.

Comment: Looking at my Macbook air keyboard and windows installed, I wish I had an `INS` key.

Comment: Hey, @adrianTNT , on your Macbook, you can simulate `Ins` with `fn`+`return`.  So to paste into putty, you can use `shift`+`fn`+`return`

Comment: BE CAREFUL DOING THIS. Some characters like `"` may look the same but be interpreted differently once you paste it into PuTTY - and this was copy pasting from notepad++ so it was plain text

Comment: @KolobCanyon yeah I noticed! copying from my editor directly to PuTTY always transformed the text, need to always "transform" to plain text by pasting to notepad before

Comment: In Windows, just right-clicking the PuTTY console window with the mouse and then hitting `enter` on the keyboard worked for me. (Note that you obviously need to Copy the password to the clipboard first.)

Comment: As of November 2, 2022 this doesn't work in Windows 11 Home.

Answer (score 3):

From the Putty Documentation

> 4.10.3 Changing the actions of the mouse buttons PuTTY's copy and paste mechanism is modelled on the Unix xterm application. The X
>   Window System uses a three-button mouse, and the convention is that
>   the left button selects, the right button extends an existing
>   selection, and the middle button pastes.
>
> Windows typically only has two mouse buttons, so in PuTTY's default
>   configuration, the right button pastes, and the middle button (if you
>   have one) extends a selection.
>
> If you have a three-button mouse and you are already used to the xterm
>   arrangement, you can select it using the "Action of mouse buttons"
>   control.

You have to change the default behavior by opening Putty > Windows > Selection > Select "xterm (Right extends, middle pastes)"

Answer (score 3):

In my case I want `Ctrl-Ins` / `Shift-Ins` only, thus, my config was:

- Window > Selection

  - Auto-copy selected text to system clipboard > `(unchecked)`
  - Mouse Paste > `(No action)`
  - `{Ctrl,Shift}+Ins` > `(System clipboard)`

You need this to VIM works:

- Terminal > Features

  - Disable application keypad mode `(checked)`

Extra:

> PuTTY operates just like a normal X terminal... 
>   Some commands will output to an "alternate" screen when the xterm terminal type is selected, such as "less" (or "vi"), which dissapears when the program exits.

However, you can disable the alternate screen with:

- Terminal > Features

  - Disable switching to alternate terminal screen `(checked)`